# How can I do a forward declaration for roxygen of a function that is defined later?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a piece of roxygen documentation that states

```
#' A numeric matrix, see \code{.postmvn}
```

however, .postmvn is defined in a file that is loaded later in the collation, therefore roxygen fails with

"there is no visible global function for .postmvn"

I know there is the `globalVariable()` solution, but I was wondering if this is the recommended way, or is there something in roxygen that allows me to say "yes, this function exists, it will be defined later"

Comment: Is it really a message from `roxygen`? I never saw that `roxygen` checks `\code{something}`. The `\code` command is just about formatting.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it seems so. If I remove the code marker, it works. I suspect it's trying to crosslink it to the code documentation, but it's not there yet